# "learn more" and "info" links in tag description, what's the difference?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, user-interface

In the tag description popup (when adding tags to questions), why do some tags have the *"learn more"* label for the link to `/tags/<tagname>/info`, while others have *"info"*?

Is that a bug, or does it indicate a subtle difference that I can't grasp in my current caffeine-deprived state?

---

[image: learn more]

---

[image: info?]

---

P.S. I see the same on MSO. [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) has *"learn more"* while [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) has *"info"*.

P.P.S. When viewing tagged questions (`/questions/tagged/<tagname>`) all tags use the same *"learn more"* label, not *"info"*. Based on this inconsistency I suspect this is a bug (retagging as such).

[image: tagged questions page uses only 'learn more']

Comment: On http://stackoverflow.com/tags, I don't see those links.

Comment: Sorry, that's in the popup when you edit tags in a question. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: +0; the freehand circles aren't red.

Answer (score 2):

I made a test with [Call a controller method within Play! template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181362/call-a-controller-method-within-play-template). For what I can see, "learn more" is used for tags without a wiki, and for tags where the wiki is more than X-line long; "info" is used in the other cases.
For example, [playback](/questions/tagged/playback) doesn't have a wiki, and I see "learn more"; [javascript-events](/questions/tagged/javascript-events) has a wiki with just a line, and I see "info."

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

I would expect "learn more" to be shown when the tag wiki (not the excerpt) contains more than X lines, and "info" in the other cases. When the tag doesn't have a tag wiki (which includes the case the tag doesn't have an excerpt nor a wiki), "learn more" doesn't have sense, as I cannot read more than what I already see in the tag excerpt.
Probably "learn more" should be shown only when the tag has a wiki with 3 or more lines of text; in that case, the link is telling me "look, there is something more you can read."

Comment: "bug" and "discussion" both have long-ish wikis and excerpts and yet they have different labels.

Comment: Even if this was by-design, the fact we have to look real hard still can only speculate on what it might mean suggest that the different labeling scheme does not serve its purpose and should be abolished/changed.

Comment: If "learn more" would be consistently used (e.g. when the tag wiki contains 3 or more lines of text) there should not be any reason to speculate. To me, "learn more" means there is something more I can read; in this case, it would mean that, after I read the excerpt, I can read the tag wiki, which is supposed to add to what I have already read in the excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate but I only seen "learn more" when editing tags.